# SSRS Complex Query Report

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am developing a report in SSRS.
My report has around 50 row headers. Data for each row header is the reult of a complex query to the database.
2 row header may/may not have data that relates to another row header.

In this case what would be the best way to create the report?
-- Do we create a procedure that gets all data to a temporary table and then generate the report using this temp table?
-- Do we create multiple datasets for this report.

Please advice on what would be the best way to proceed.

I read somewhere about using Link wherein data is retrieved from the post gre database (project uses postGreSql db) to the local sql server that SSRS provides.
Report then retrieves data from the local sql server to generate the report.
Thoughts?

Comment: You can use any approach that's suits you according to your performance but try to format and get data in single dataset because that will help you to use all column headers in same tablix because it's headache in `SSRS` to combine the result of the two different datasets into one tablix.

Comment: Edited the question to add another approach I read about...thoughts?

Comment: I never used the PostGreSql with `SSRS` but i think  the SSRS gives direct access to PostGreSql  using different drivers that would be give the good performance over copying the data from PostGreSql  to sql server and then fetching it from there. You can try both the approaches for the large dataset or the complex query and check the performance, as I am not sure about it.

Comment: yes, way to go. i usually make a procedure. first thing it does is build a temp table, get data in from different data sources via openquery, match it, check it, calculate some stuff, then at the end of the procedure select * from the temp table, which will be the ssrs dataset. you can also persist it in a table, and use this table from ssrs (if the procedure takes a long time)

Answer (score 0):

You are best using a stored procedure as the source. It is easy to optimize the stored procedure so as to get the best performance so the report runs fast.

Assembling all your data so that you can use a single dataset to represent it would be the way to go.